# Hive to CSV - Special Characters Handling

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, special-characters

I have a Hive Table which I am writing to a csv file in my local using the command line. I am using the following code:

```
hive -e 'select * from my_Table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /home/myfile.csv
```

But in the output csv file, the records containing special characters are being split into a new line somehow which should not be the case.

```
 Rohan,KurunÃ¤s Ã
 korson,rohan.furuna@company.se,+1 11 111 18 00,VÃâSTERÃâ¦S,Sweden,SvalgÃ¥ngen
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Looks like a problem of **code page conversion**. Hadoop works with UTF-8 but clearly the machine where you are viewing the CSV does not use UTF-8. You should run `file myfile.csv` to get a diagnostic then experiment with `iconv` to convert UTF-8 characters to something your system supports (e.g. Windows-1252).

Comment: And if you really have special chars that provoke line breaks, look at the file with a serious text editor (e.g. Notepad++) and the hexadecimal dump feature, to identify the rogue chars so that you can `tr` them. Note that a hardcore Linux  user would use `od -cx` for the hex dump, but clearly you are not there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use CTAS to create the CSV file and use CopyToLocal command to copy file to desired location.

```
set mapreduce.job.reduces=1;
create table mytmptable ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' location 'hdfs://mylocation' as select * from my_Table;
drop table mytmptable;
```

Setting number of reducers to 1 will create one file.